# Call VSTO Excel Plugin from Macro Button VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto

I created my VSTO Excel Plugin and want to call this from VBA Macro Button.
But I am facing an issue while clicking on the button

> Error: Object variable or with block variable not set.

I add this in my ThisAddin file

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    refreshConnection = new RefreshConnection();
    Application.COMAddIns.Item("ProgID").Object = refreshConnection;
}
```

In place of progID I used my ID I created.

And in another File where my Excel plugin Ribbon button class is there which consist of my excel plugin button click
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] this I included before my class.

Below is my VBA macro module code

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim addIn As COMAddIn
    Dim automationObject As Object

    Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("ProgId")
    Set automationObject = addIn.Object

    automationObject.RefreshWorkbookConnection
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Please provide me the step-by-step implementation how can I achieve this.

Comment: Which line of code is giving the error message?

Comment: Set automationObject = addIn.Object
from this line

Comment: Get infos about your comaddins:

`Dim a As COMAddIn

For Each a In Application.COMAddIns
Debug.Print "project id: "; a.progID; " project Description: "; a.Description; " is connected: "; a.Connect; " object is nothing:"; a.Object Is Nothing
Next a`

Comment: This is the output i get and my main focus is on Project ID: LoginToAtScale, Project Description: LoginToAtScale, Is Connected: False, Object is Nothing: True

Comment: But here you got all information. It is not connected.

Comment: What is `RefreshConnection` object declaration?

Comment: I created Ribbon class in my excel plugin whose name is RefreshConnection.cs,which consist of btnRefreshConnectionClick() which i want to trigger from my macro thats why i used this.